# is Milner'c CCS turing complete

Tags: concurrency, lambda-calculus

So one can say a language is Turing complete if it meets some criteria. Milner's Calculus of Communicating Systems (CCS) is Turing complete. However, I could not find a proof for this. Is there any proof for this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computational theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by giving an encoding of any known Turing-complete language into CCS, you can establish its Turing completeness.  The construction of such an encoding is a proof.  This has been done (to my knowledge) in several contexts, but the most direct one is likely the [encoding of the Pi calculus into CCS](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.210.9283&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: i have another doubt whether turing complete and turing powerful are the same or turing powerful < turing complete

Comment: The two terms mean the same thing.